# How to structure my nodejs code? fat model / skinny controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, model-view-controller, mongoose

My code works, but I understand it's best to have fat models and skinny controllers.

However, I am using 3 different models and have unfortunately made my controller fat. What is the best way to organize this code (with fat model / skinny controller concept)? I've been reading on code structure, but I'm a bit unsure of best practices.

Controller:

```
var Product = require('../models/product');
var Collection = require('../models/collection');
var Vote = require('../models/vote');

exports.topSearch = function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body, "search product")

  Product.search({
      query_string: {
        query: req.body.search
      }
    },req.body.searchObject,
    function(err, results) {
      if (err) console.log('ERR', err);
      if (results) {
        var data = results.hits.hits;

        Vote.find({
          user: req.user._id
        }, function(err, votes) {
          if (!err) {
            for (var i = 0; i < votes.length; i++) {
              for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                if (data[j]['_id'] == votes[i]['product']) {
                  data[j]['voteId'] = votes[i]['_id'];
                  data[j]['userVote'] = votes[i]['vote'];
                }
              }
            }
          }

        Collection.find({
          user: req.user._id
        }, function(err, collections) {
          if (!err) {
            for (var i = 0; i < collections.length; i++) {
              for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                if (data[j]['_id'] == collections[i]['product']) {
                  console.log('match')
                  data[j]['collected'] = true;
                  data[j]['collectId'] = collections[i]['_id'];
                  data[j]['favorite'] = collections[i]['favorite'];
                } else if (data[j]['_id'] !== collections[i]['product'] && data[j]['collected'] !== true) {
                  data[j]['collected'] = false;
                }
              }
            }
            res.send(data);
          }
        });
      });

      } else {
        res.send({
          errmsg: 'results not defined'
        })
      }
    });
};
```

I then call this in my route:

```
  app.post('/products-search', users.ensureAuthenticated, products.topSearch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate file under models or functions, where you can do all your model based processing related to "topSearch" and then simply call a single method inside of your controller.

Use something like **async.js** to better handle callbacks and flow.

I personally follow the folder structure defined in this repo.

[better-node-express-app-structure](https://github.com/rahil471/node-express-app-structure)

And sometimes I add subfolders into models and controllers depending on the complexity.

Frequently used select queries can be directly exported as independent functions to facilitate reusability.